# Maintaining Structure of Pdf while Extracting Data

Tags: java, pdf, itext

[image]
I am trying to extract the data from PDF documents using the iText library. I am able to extract PDF document but I am not able to maintain the structure of the PDF file while parsing.

I tried with Apache Tika and pdfbox also but still I am not able to maintain the structure of the file. Code which I tried so far is as follows:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.TextExtractionStrategy;

public class ExtractPageContent {

    public static final String source = "C:/Users/xyz/Test.pdf";

    public static final String dest = "C:/Users/xyz/Test.txt";

    public void parsePdf(String pdf, String txt) throws IOException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
        PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(txt));
        TextExtractionStrategy strategy;
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            strategy = parser.processContent(i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
            out.println(strategy.getResultantText());
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        reader.close();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new ExtractPageContent().parsePdf(source, dest);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by maintaining the structure of the PDF?

Comment: Refer to Image attached in url i.stack.imgur.com/pn1GQ.png When I use pdfbox or itext read in straight horizontal line while it contains 2 columns. have to read it forst left column and then right column

Comment: Never put more information into comments. Edit your question instead. And for the next time: check out the help center to understand what information should be provided with "good questions".

Comment: *When I use pdfbox or itext read in straight horizontal line while it contains 2 columns* - the text extractors both in iText and in PDFBox expect text either to be drawn in reading order, no sorting required (in iText: `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy`, in PDFBox `PDFTextStripper.setSortByPosition(false)`), or they sort it as single-column and horizontal (in iText: `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`, in PDFBox `PDFTextStripper.setSortByPosition(true)`). You can try and improve the code in either library to first try and recognize columns and extract accordingly. The *recognizing* is not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. it worked for me. You need to use PDFBox api. It's the best library to extract text from the pdf document.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripperByArea;

public void readText(){
try {
    PDDocument document = null;
    document = PDDocument.load(new File("test.pdf"));
    document.getClass();
    if (!document.isEncrypted()) {
        PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
        stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
        PDFTextStripper Tstripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        String st = Tstripper.getText(document);
        System.out.println("Text:" + st);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't use the `PDFTextStripperByArea stripper` for anything, does it? And in which way does it *maintain the structure of the file* as the OP requires?

Comment: Refer to Image attached in url http://i.stack.imgur.com/pn1GQ.png When I use pdfbox or itext read in straight horizontal line while it contains 2 columns. have to read it forst left column and then right column

Comment: @mkl .. I have used **stripper** object to set the sort by position property true...
`stripper.setSortByPosition(true);`

Comment: *I have used stripper object to set the sort by position property true* - but as you do not extract using `stripper` but using `Tstripper`, that *sort by position property* of `stripper` makes no difference at all. Thus, you don't use the `stripper` for anything.